# Difference in timestamp between two REST APIs

Tags: python, networking, time, coinbase-api, binance

this is the first time I use StackOverflow, so sorry if I missed something.

I have been working with two REST APIs that report "server time".

I am interested in measuring somehow the difference (since I do not have access to the API servers), if any, between my computer time and both reported server times in order to be able to order the data gathered from both APIs correctly with respect to time.

The closest metric I could come up with was time_appconnect from [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), but still I think it does not solve my problem. Also I think I cannot apply solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389417/synchronization-of-clocks-between-two-remote-computers) since I do not have access to the servers.

Is there any method for achieving this? Is ordering the data based on arrival time the best way to go?

In case it helps I'm trying to compare Binance [server time](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time) with Coinbase [server time](https://api.pro.coinbase.com/time)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: One would hope those times are within at least a second or two of each other. Then there's no really good way to figure out whether any of those reported values are off and by how much, since the delay in network transmission is unaccountable for. You'd need a protocol like NTP to be able to get a correct time value *despite* network latency, but that simple REST API alone doesn't do that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! That was more or less what I was suspecting, just wanted to check I wasn't missing something